# Can't run a Flutter app with NodeJS API on a physical device

Tags: node.js, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter app with NodeJS API and trying to run it on a physical device; but it gives me the message of *"Connection timed out"*,

I'm using my `IPV4` and I've tried to run it on an emulator with the ip `10.0.2.2` and it worked,
So anyone have a solution for that? I've been trying for a lot of time

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is only works on emulator, if you want to run on physical device you have to use your local ip address. Same like 192.168.1.223.

Comment: I said I tried my local ip but it it didn't work, help please.

Comment: First of all, access the your api endpoint on explorer and make sure its working and then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your computer and physical device have to be connected to the same Network. To access the webpage from a Physical Device you need to use the IP address of your computer instead of `localhost`.

1. Start your NodeJS server on 0.0.0.0:8000 or your default port.
2. Check your computer's IP using:

- `ipconfig` on Windows
- `ip addr` on Linux
- `ifconfig` on macOS

3. Use the IP Address you obtained on the physical device.

Attaching an example from Windows's `ipconfig`

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : atheesh.org
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ee8c:b3b2:76cb:4930
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.110
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::be0f:9aff:fe6a:c031
                                    10.0.0.254
```

Now, On your physical device you'll be using (maybe IPv4, your choice) http://10.0.0.110:8000 and it'll work if your physical device is on the same network.

Comment: My computer & android device are connected on the same wifi, can you explain more about running my server on 0.0.0.0 , by the way I'm using the port 3500, thanks for help.

Comment: `app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`

where 3000 is the port, since yours is 3500, that should be what you put there

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work, I tried accessing the api from flutter using 0.0.0.0 ip & my IPV4

Comment: my phone is on the same network as the laptop, I tried your solution but it didn't work neither

Comment: @SomaAz what distro are you using? Linux?

Comment: @ParkingMaster No I'm using windows

Comment: So did what the user in this answer did. List your IP address from windows ("ipconfig") and then go to it using that IP and the port you started on.

Comment: When you listen to `0.0.0.0` you need to access it using your PC's IP address (eg. 192.168.0.25). `0.0.0.0` means listen to all network cards. It is impossible to connect to `0.0.0.0` since a request must be made to a specific server, not all servers on the internet. However it is possible to listen to `0.0.0.0` since your server should be able to accept a connection from any client.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solve it the right way, but it works
I used ngrok package that makes the app working on the global internent just with (node run)

I call it with https and not http

Comment: Good job getting it to work. If you want a free alternative to ngrok, try using [localtunnel](https://loca.lt). It's free, easy to set up, and you can have a custom subdomain. Check it out, I found it much better. Check out the GitHub to use more advanced stuff.